# Show Windows Forms balloon tips 

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, tooltip

I have this code

```
if (IsValid(textBox.Text))
{
    toolTip.Hide(textBox);
}
else
{
    toolTip.Show("Please enter an valid text", textBox);
    textBox.Select();
}
```

It work fine as normal tooltip, but when I set `IsBallon` to `true` on `toolTip` it stops showing at all.

Comment: Where are you calling this code, I created a textbox, button, and tooltip on a form, set IsBalloon to true and false and it worked both times.  I am just checking if the textbox is empty on a button click in order to decide to show the tooltip or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/1b0b026f-90ea-4cd3-b372-45de2d60ca0c/

and

http://www.debugging.com/bug/20204

Try the solution suggested in the latter:

> I'd use regedit to check the registry setting for which the key is as follows:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\EnableBalloonTips
>   If it's zero, they're disabled. You'd then need to change it to 1 and reboot the machine.

(EDIT: Adjusted the registry key after reading further in the linked page)

Comment: Or in other words, the user has disabled balloon tips intentionally.  It works, don't fix it :)

Comment: Or if you want to be a good citizen, go and check that registry value on startup and set your IsBalloon property accordingly.